# \includegraphics without changing text symbols?

Tags: graphics

I'm trying to include a MATLAB figure in LaTeX. The MATLAB figure has this text:

```
t1 = ['\phi = ', num2str(phi(k)),'^\circ'];
text(Pmax*1.05,sqrt(-X*Pmax*tp+E^2/2)*.95,t1,'rotation',90,'FontSize',8)
```

and the figure looks fine but when I `\includegraphics` the figure into LaTeX the degree symbol (`\circ`) changes to another Greek letter, a gamma I think.

My LaTeX code looks like this

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{matlab/part1/pvfig}
\caption{Insert caption}
\end{figure}
```

Also the colors of the figure disappear.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be a problem on MATLAB's side rather than LaTeX. Without seeing the actual image (or the entire code used to generate the image in MATLAB), there's not much that can be done. If you're interested in LaTeX formatting of text within a graphic, perhaps using [`psfrag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) would be a suitable alternative?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the way you are using / printing the figure.

1. You shouldn't use the way `Save as` instead use:

   ```
   print -depsc -loose filename.eps
   ```
2. Or you can use `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` in your tex-file.
3. Or you can use [`matfig2pgf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12962) Now you need the package `pgf`.

But this question is a little bit off topic. Maybe [stack exchange mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matlab) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to convert Matlab's `.fig` files into `LaTeX` figures. You could also try [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022). I must confess I have not tried it yet, but I'm pretty sure it works well.